# Firebase auth:import (v 3.2.1) fails importing Parse users

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following Firebase's documentation, 
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-ios#migrate-accounts, to migrate my exported Parse users into Firebase.

`firebase auth:import --debug --hash-algo BCRYPT ../sample.json`

It fails on all records with the same error:

> Error: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid value for ByteString: $2a$10$FGbVQ4bhehr6Z2XBoiF9BO2H.3EXTV9pRRf2ahHFimltnOg1oagPO

I have verified that the hash is good by rehashing a known password using this online tool https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator.

Additionally, when I removed the `passwordHash` field to see if I could get the import to work at all, it did, but the email fields are lost despite seeing them in the verbose debug console output:

> >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/uploadAccount users=[email=xxxxx+jsonimport@gmail.com, localId=1, displayName=jasonimport], hashAlgorithm=BCRYPT, targetProjectId=comicchameleon-2813e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should base64 encode the bcrypt hash string and set the encoded string to `passwordHash`. This is documented [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#csv-format).

The following NodeJs code can do the base64 encoding.

```
new Buffer('$2a$10$FGbVQ4bhehr6Z2XBoiF9BO2H.3EXTV9pRRf2ahHFimltnOg1oagPO').toString('base64');
```

I'm not sure what's the cause of missing email. Could you paste your sample.json here?

Comment: thanks this worked! SO says I'm not supposed to just thank you so I'll complain about one thing (if you are indeed part of Firebase as it seems you might be). This page https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-ios#migrate-accounts doesn't mention base64 encoding the bcryptPassword field from Parse and further implies the original data should work by using the same exact string for passwordHash in the "transformed" Firebase input.

Comment: @Jason How did you export the users from Parse?